# Switching between different versions of an app with Qt Installer Framework

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I have an app which makes specific files. Those files only can be opened by the app. Since we release updates often, sometimes users want to go to previous versions of the app to open old files. Hence, I should make a way to switch between different versions quickly by using Qt Installer Framework.

I think to upload different versions as repositories and let user select one of them.

- User should have ability to select only one out of them, other
  selections should be unchecked automatically.
- Then Installer must uninstall the previous version and install the selected one instead.

[image]

I've searched and these two questions are more or less similar to my question.

- https://forum.qt.io/topic/98000/qt-installer-framework-exclude-components
- [Switch between variants of component in Qt Installer Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107272/switch-between-variants-of-component-in-qt-installer-framework)

Moreover, I have been through every single examples in Qt Installer Framework documentation.

Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to check/uncheck selection according to users selection and to uninstall and install accordingly.

Comment: Or any other way to do that?